# light gbm - python API vs Scikit-learn API

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am trying to apply LightGBM and have gone through the Python API [documentation](http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html).

Is there any difference between Training API and Scikit-learn API? Can we use both the APIs to achieve same result for the same problem?

Answer (score 10):

The short answer: yes, they will provide identical results if you will configure them in identical ways.

The reason is that sklearn API is just a wrapper around the "native training" API, which in turn is a wrapper around the backend C++ library. At the end, this is your choice to make. I personally would advice in favour of the sklearn API. The 2 major advantages are:

- you can make use of full sklearn toolkit (pipelines with data preprocessing, hyperparameter optimisation, model evalueation, etc)
- you can switch between different model in a painless way, i.e. your input data has the same format (`pd.DataFrame` or `np.ndarray`), trainign interface is the same and you can switch between sklearn models, lightgbm, xgboost, catboost or vowpal wabbit by simply instantiating different objects and passing them through the same procedure.